# Attached properties in Template WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have Attached Property and ControlTemplate using the attached property.
Attached Propery:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace NoteProjectV2.classes.frmtopicclasses
{
    class togglebuttonimage : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty togglebuttonimagesource = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(togglebuttonimage), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));


        public static void Settogglebuttonimagesource(UIElement element, string value)
        {
            element.SetValue(togglebuttonimagesource, value);
        }

        public static string Gettogglebuttonimagesource(UIElement element)
        {
            return (string)element.GetValue(togglebuttonimagesource);
        }


    }
}
```

This is my control template (I used this in togglebutton)

```
<Application x:Class="NoteProjectV2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoteProjectV2"
             xmlns:m="clr-namespace:NoteProjectV2.classes.frmtopicclasses"
             StartupUri="frmTopic.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="togglebutton_topic_menu_normal" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border Name="border">
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="Black"/>

                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>
                            <Image Width="22" Height="22" Name="image" >
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style>
   Only This is not working===============>  <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding Path=(m:togglebuttonimage.togglebuttonimagesource),RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I used attached propery in code:I also added namespace above

```
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:NoteProjectV2.classes.frmtopicclasses"
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource togglebutton_topic_menu_normal}" m:togglebuttonimage.togglebuttonimagesource="accept.png" />
```

But this is not working Where is my problem?

Comment: You do not follow the naming convention of dependency properties. Please have a look [here in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139641/how-to-use-attached-property-within-a-style)

Comment: And you certainly agree that `togglebuttonimagesource` is a horribly name of a property, not to mention method names lile `Settogglebuttonimagesource`. Use [Pascal Casing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to the `Register` and `RegisterAttached` method of class DependencyProperty is the name of the property.

While you are using the name `"ImageSource"`, it should actually be `"ToggleButtonImageSource"` (which already uses proper casing). Note also that as long as you only declare attached properties, the owning class does not need to be derived from DependencyObject.

```
public class ToggleButtonImage
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToggleButtonImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ToggleButtonImageSource", typeof(string), typeof(ToggleButtonImage));

    public static void SetToggleButtonImageSource(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ToggleButtonImageSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetToggleButtonImageSource(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(ToggleButtonImageSourceProperty);
    }
}
```

---

Besides that, you should better use `ImageSource` instead of `string` as the type of the property.